# Android - Error creating folder

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a new folder in the external storage of the emulator. It's working once, but not in the second time.
I tried debugging, and this is the debug log :

```
>> Let's debug why this directory isn't being created: 
Is it working?: false
Does it exist?: false
What is the full URI?: file:/storage/emulated/0/Notepad/Apr%203,%202018%2012:27:46%20PM
--
Can we write to this file?: false
>> We can't write! Do we have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?
We do have permission - the problem lies elsewhere.
Are we even allowed to read this file?: false
--
>> End of debugging.
```

And this is the error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Notepad/Apr 3, 2018 12:27:46 PM/database: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It's working well on API 23 and API 27, but it's failing on API 17 and API 19.

What could be wrong? Why isn't the folder being created?
I have read and write permission, so I'm sure that's not the error, it's working on API 23.

**Edit**

This is the code before the log

```
val backupFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notepad")
if (!backupFolder.exists()) backupFolder.mkdir()

val date = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(System.currentTimeMillis())
val newBackupFolder = File(backupFolder, date)
newBackupFolder.mkdir()
```

and this is after the log :

```
val backupFile = File(newBackupFolder, "database")
databaseFile.copyTo(backupFile)
```

Comment: `No such file or directory` This means you are doing some file operation so folder or file not found which you are creating

Comment: @AmjadKhan Please check the edit, I'm already creating the folder before trying to copy, but it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a folder with `:` present in the path.

This to my knowledge is an invalid character. It is definitely invalid on Windows. (try creating a folder with a colon, and you will see the warning Windows throws)

Try formatting the date part to use `.` (full stops) instead. As visually it should be similar, and is a valid character.

Try a format like below for a directory friendly format:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss")
```

Comment: Never thought that would make an error, it worked! Tho why is it working on Android 21?

Comment: @AhmadSattout Not sure about that. But this way is definitely safer on all devices :) Glad its working for you